# Building a package that have dependency on either library x or library y

Tags: dependency-management, bower

I am trying to build a package using bower that will require bootstrap. At the moment there are 2 trees for bootstrap, the original Less version and the new Sass version. How can I add in the package dependency that it should look for either version of bootstrap?

So instead of:

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": ">= 3.0.0"
}
```

To be something like:

(this is a pseudo code, it wont work)

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": ">= 3.0.0" || "bootstrap-sass-official": ">= 3.0.0"
}
```

Can this be done?

Comment: The question is, what is the real need for such approach ?

Comment: @rashad as I mentioned above, I am building a plugin that requires bootstrap. There are 2 trees for bootstrap one is built on Sass and the other is built on Less ... It makes no since to try to install one if the user is using the other. That's all